# Converting angular.element() into template in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to transform a directive that currently uses angular.element() into a template, but so far the template one is not working. 
Being new to AngularJS, I assume I made some big-ass mistake, but so far I can't see it. 
Any pointers?

Here's the original:

```
app.directive('theDirective',  ['musicInfoService',
function(musicInfoService) {
return {
restrict: 'A',
scope: { position: '@', last: '@', release: '=',
    artist: '=', versions: '@' },
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

  element.bind('click', function() {
    // Highlight clicked element
    angular.element(document.querySelector('.clicked')).removeClass('clicked');
    element.addClass('clicked');

    // Create the collapse element or select existing one
    var collapseQuery = document.querySelector('#collapse');
    var collapse = collapseQuery === null ?
      angular.element('<div id="collapse" ng-controller="VersionController" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12"> \
            <div class="inner"> \
              <ul> \
                <li class="title">{{release.title}}</li> \
                <li class="row top" ng-show="versions"> \
                  <div class="col-md-1">Year</div> \
                  <div class="col-md-3">Format</div> \
                  <div class="col-md-3">Label</div> \
                  <div class="col-md-2">Country</div> \
                  <div class="col-md-2">Cat. Nº</div> \
                </li> \
                <li class="row" ng-show="versions" ng-repeat="version in versions | filter: \'!file\' | orderBy: version.released"> \
                  <div class="col-md-1">{{(version.released | release:4) || \'-----\'}}</div> \
                  <div class="col-md-3">{{version.format}}</div> \
                  <div class="col-md-3">{{version.label}}</div> \
                  <div class="col-md-2">{{version.country}}</div> \
                  <div class="col-md-2">{{version.catno}}</div> \
                </li> \
                <li class="row top" ng-hide="!release.format"> \
                  <div class="col-md-1">Year</div> \
                  <div class="col-md-3">Format</div> \
                  <div class="col-md-3">Label</div> \
                </li> \
                <li class="row" ng-hide="!release.format"> \
                  <div class="col-md-1">{{release.year}}</div> \
                  <div class="col-md-3">{{release.format}}</div> \
                  <div class="col-md-8">{{release.label}}</div> \
                </li> \
              </ul> \
            </div> \
          </div>') :
      angular.element(collapseQuery);

    // Based on the position of the clicked element calculate the rounded number up to the nearest multiple of four
    var calculatedPosition = Math.ceil(scope.position / 4) * 4;

    // Get the element at the calculated position or the last one
    var calculatedQuery = document.querySelector('[position="' + calculatedPosition + '"]');
    if (calculatedQuery === null) calculatedQuery = document.querySelector('[last="true"]');;

    var calculatedElement = angular.element(calculatedQuery);

    // Insert the collapse element after the element at the calculated position
    calculatedElement.after(collapse);
    // Highlight the calculated element
    angular.element(document.querySelector('.calculated')).removeClass('calculated');
    calculatedElement.addClass('calculated');
  });

  scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    element.unbind('click');
  });
}
};
}
]);
```

And the converted one:

```
  app.directive('theDirective',  ['musicInfoService',
  function(musicInfoService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: { position: '@', last: '@', release: '=', artist: '='},
    template: '<div id="collapse" ng-controller="VersionController" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12"> \
                <div class="inner"> \
                  <ul> \
                    <li class="title">{{release.title}}</li> \
                    <li class="row top" ng-show="versions"> \
                      <div class="col-md-1">Year</div> \
                      <div class="col-md-3">Format</div> \
                      <div class="col-md-3">Label</div> \
                      <div class="col-md-2">Country</div> \
                      <div class="col-md-2">Cat. Nº</div> \
                    </li> \
                    <li class="row" ng-show="versions" ng-repeat="version in versions | filter: \'!file\' | orderBy: version.released"> \
                      <div class="col-md-1">{{(version.released | release:4) || \'-----\'}}</div> \
                      <div class="col-md-3">{{version.format}}</div> \
                      <div class="col-md-3">{{version.label}}</div> \
                      <div class="col-md-2">{{version.country}}</div> \
                      <div class="col-md-2">{{version.catno}}</div> \
                    </li> \
                    <li class="row top" ng-hide="!release.format"> \
                      <div class="col-md-1">Year</div> \
                      <div class="col-md-3">Format</div> \
                      <div class="col-md-3">Label</div> \
                    </li> \
                    <li class="row" ng-hide="!release.format"> \
                      <div class="col-md-1">{{release.year}}</div> \
                      <div class="col-md-3">{{release.format}}</div> \
                      <div class="col-md-8">{{release.label}}</div> \
                    </li> \
                  </ul> \
                </div> \
              </div>',
    replace: false,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      elem.bind('click', function() {
        // Highlight clicked element
        elem(document.querySelector('.clicked')).removeClass('clicked');
        elem.addClass('clicked');

        // Create the collapse element or select existing one
        var collapseQuery = document.querySelector('#collapse');
        var collapse = collapseQuery === null ?
        elem(collapseQuery)

        // Based on the position of the clicked element calculate the rounded number up to the nearest multiple of four
        var calculatedPosition = Math.ceil(scope.position / 4) * 4;

        // Get the element at the calculated position or the last one
        var calculatedQuery = document.querySelector('[position="' + calculatedPosition + '"]');
        if (calculatedQuery === null) calculatedQuery = document.querySelector('[last="true"]');;

        var calculatedElement = angular.element(calculatedQuery);

        // Insert the collapse element after the element at the calculated position
        calculatedElement.after(collapse);

      });

      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        elem.unbind('click');
      });
    }
  };
}
]);
```

**EDIT**: This directive comes from [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fsC51vS7Ily3X3CVmxSZ?p=preview).

**EDIT II**: And here's [the example](http://plnkr.co/edit/NiD5Md8AHi2amYipRndd?p=preview) where I'm trying to implement it.

Comment: Does the console show any errors?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on line 89 (var calculatedPosition = Math.ceil(scope.position / 4) * 4;). The thing is that I'm not sure if I missed something on the conversion, I'm not particularly fluent in js.

Comment: @EliranMalka I think that parenthesis is added by the console. He has it right in the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
    var collapse = collapseQuery === null ?
    elem(collapseQuery)
```

You lack of an "else" alternative in the ternary operator. And the semicolon

```
    var collapse = collapseQuery === null ?
    elem(collapseQuery) : "Some other option";
```

Your Controller code is very confusing, I gave up reading it. Try to define it in a more "angular" way.

```
app.controller('Ctrl', ["$scope" , "musicInfoService", 
  function ($scope, musicInfoService) {
    $scope.getDetails = function (id) {
      // Your function goes here.
    };

    $scope.search = function () {
      musicInfoService.doSomething();
    };
  }
]);
```

That might not be the problem though. You have

```
ng-controller="VersionController"
```

And I don't see any definition of it. Jst like Ctrl, VersionController needs a definition. The error you get is quite clear.

Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'VersionController' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: Tried it, still failing (now with Error: [ng:areq] )
I made a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NiD5Md8AHi2amYipRndd?p=preview)

Comment: @EricMitjans Take a look

Comment: Last hint: Replace to this. ng-controller="Ctrl"